# How to block incoming addresses in CC from a Gmail filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

How can I build a Gmail filter to select persons by listing them in "Has the words" but not to include another person's mail just because the select person's address is in the other person's CC? Or in another persons TO except if the mail is sent from me?
For example: I want the filter to include mail to and from Mary. So I put Mary's address in "Has the words". This collects all mail from Mary to me and from me to Mary, but it also collects mail from Paul to me because Paul includes Mary in his mail-to addresses. I don't want to collect Paul's mail with this filter because I have a different filter that collects his mail. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of what it is you're asking. Could you clarify what you're trying to do, maybe with some examples?

Comment: Al E. -- I have edited the top-post to with an example to make it more clear. - Stan

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
(from:myemail@gmail.com to:mary@gmail.com) OR (from:mary@gmail.com to:myemail@gmail.com)
```

This will find all conversations with a message where your address is in the `from:` field and Mary's is in the `to:` field, or your address is in the `to:` field and Mary's is in the `from:` field. If your address is only in the `cc:` field, it shouldn't get caught by this.

Note that if you're using conversation mode, this will probably bring back more than you expect, because the search will return whole conversations. All it takes is for one message of the conversation to meet this criteria.

You can get even more granular by excluding `cc:` messages to either of you.

```
(from:myemail@gmail.com to:mary@gmail.com -cc:mary@gmail.com) OR (from:mary@gmail.com to:myemail@gmail.com -cc:myemail@gmail.com)
```

In my experiments, though, I didn't find any difference in the two searches.

You can also shortcut your email address with "me", like so:

```
(from:me to:mary@gmail.com) OR (from:mary@gmail.com to:me)
```